# I want a simple, expandable Treeview left nav menu for an ASP.Net MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview, menu

OK, I've bound an asp:Treeview control to a sitemap datasource, but I can't figure out any of the options ... All I want it to do is:

1. Load "closed" - that is with all nodes collapsed
2. close all other nodes when a new one is opened
3. Stay open the way it was on the previous page
4. Give me the option of changing the open/closed/empty images

Is that too much to ask?  Shouldn't the basic .NET control do that so I don't have to go find a 3rd-party one?  Am I just not getting it?  Can I configure it to do those things?

Comment: Is this actually an ASP.NET MVC site?  You don't use the classic ASP.NET controls, such as asp:TreeView with an MVC site.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, if this is a MVC site, then it looks like [a jQuery based menu is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167179/replacement-of-asptreeview-for-asp-net-mvc-application).